# nginx location rewrite anything after / to root

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Let's say I have example.com and I'd like to rewrite anything after / to root, i.e. example.com/one/two?whatever=foo should go back to example.com

I've tried the following:

```
location = / {
    index  index.html;
}

location / {
    rewrite ^ / permanent;
}
```

But this gives me too many redirects error. I could go route using regex to specify all the allowed/disallowed characters, but that would make it too ugly/long/complex.

Why does the exact match can't tell the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the `index` directive to perform an internal rewrite from `/` to `/index.html`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

`nginx` then restarts the search for a matching `location`, which results in a loop.

You could add an exact match for the `/index.html` URI, for example:

```
location = /index.html { }
```

If `index.html` pulls in local resources (e.g. css, js, images), you will also need to handle those URIs specially.